# Edge versus vertex assignment in graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider a graph $G = (V,E)$. Let $x \in \{-1,1\}^V$ be a label assignment to vertices of the graph and $z \in \{-1,1\}^E$ be a label assignment to edges of the graph. We say that $z$ is compatible with $x$ if for any edge $e = \{i,j\} \in E$, we have $x_i x_j = z_e$.

One can think of $x$ as dividing $V$ into two classes and a compatible $z$ determining whether an edge is between two classes or within, according to $x$.

Question: For what edge label assignments $z$, one can find a compatible vertex label assignment $x$? (My guess is that this problem should have already been studied before and has a name, or is trivial.)

Comment: In a connected graph there are either no or two ($x$ and $-x$) compatible assigments. And we have existence iff the product of $z(e)$ along any (minimal) closed path is $+1$.

Comment: How do you prove this? (I can see its necessity: $\prod_{e \in \text{closed path}} z_e = \prod_{i \; \text{on the path}} x_i^2)$ Is there a description that is easier to check? In addition, is there a description of the convex hull of those $z$ for which there is at least one compatible assignment.